# Qt jumpToFrame() is not working

Tags: qt, animation, gif

I have this code that responds to a checked() signal from a checkbox. It's supposed to change the .gif playing in a label to another .gif with a different color. I wanted to make the transition smooth, so I tried to use the jumpToFrame() command. The code is listed below:

```
 void Scoreboard::poweractive1(bool checked)
{
    if(checked==true) //checkbox is checked
    {
        int frame=logo1->currentFrameNumber(); //get current frame number
        logo1->stop(); //stops previous gif
        ui->label_96->clear(); //clear contents of label containing gif
        ui->label_96->setMovie(logo1_or); // place second gif on the label
        logo1_or->jumpToFrame(frame); // jumps frame number of second gif to the frame number
        logo1_or->start(); //start gif animation
    }else // same conditions as above, except it reverses the actions above
    {
        ui->label_95->clear();
        ui->label_95->setPixmap(*bl_divider1);
        int frame=logo1_or->currentFrameNumber();
        logo1_or->stop();
        ui->label_96->clear();
        ui->label_96->setMovie(logo1);
        logo1->jumpToFrame(frame);
        logo1->start();
    }
}
```

TL;DR version: How do I make a QMovie start at a specific frame?

Comment: What value your `frame` variable has and what `logo1_or->jumpToFrame(frame)` returns? It should return `true` on success and `false` otherwise. Also is the count of frames in `logo1` and `logo1_or` the same?

Comment: 1.The variable frame contains the current frame number of the previous .gif animation when stopped. 
2. Yes, the .gif files pointed by logo1 and logo1_or have the same number of frames.

Comment: I ask you what exactly value has this variable.

Comment: It's a dynamic int value. As I said above, the value of frame is recorded as soon as a checkbox is checked, i.e. the value of frame is the frame number of the currently playing gif as the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: You don't understand me. It's clear for me what this variable mean and what value it should contain. I asked you what EXACTLY it contains when this code runs. Check this with debugger or make output with qDebug or what ever.

Comment: I tried checking its value. It's getting different values whenever I recheck the checkbox at different times.

Comment: What if you swap this two lines: ` logo1_or->start(); logo1_or->jumpToFrame(frame); `

Comment: It jumps to the exact frame, but the animation is paused.

Comment: Ok, then call `logo1_or->setPaused(false)` after `umpToFrame`

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem and found that `movie->jumpToFrame(int )` works fine if set `movie->setCacheMode(QMovie::CacheAll);`

Answer (score 0):

I found that you have to jump to each frame in order.

```
QMovie *m = new QMovie(path);
m->start();
m->setPaused(true);
// jumpToFrame only seems to work if you load the frames in order
int frame = 20;
bool ok = m->jumpToFrame(frame);
assert(ok); // fails
for(int i=0; i<=frame; i++)
{
    bool ok = m->jumpToFrame(i);
    assert(ok); //succeeds
}
```

Discovered this by accident but it makes sense. Possibly would work differently if the gif had already played a whole loop.